# how to use JAVA to get the output of nload on Mac

Tags: java, macos, command-line

I'm using nload to get the realtime bandwidth. I want to use java to collect those data and dump them into a file. But it does't work with the normal code. It shows nothing. Can someone tell me how to grab data using command line like nload or top? They are showing dynamic data rather than output static strings like pwd or ls.

```
private String executeCommand(String command) {

        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

        Process p;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("top");
            p.waitFor();
            BufferedReader reader = 
                            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

                        String line = "";           
            while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
                output.append(line + "\n");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return output.toString();

    }
```

Comment: I'm just curious why you'd use a Java to collect and save the output rather than simply do `top -l 1 > output.txt` ?

Comment: @StephenP it's part of a JAVA project, of course bash script is the best way, but I need to collect the data from JAVA.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. BTW, the name of the language is just the word **Java**, not **JAVA** which implies an acronym or initialism.

Comment: @StephenP haha, thanks for correction. Actually, I want to monitor the bandwidth, the original question is how to get data from nload, since few people are using nload, and it's the same problem as top, because both of them are refreshing the output data. However top can dump only one frame data, while the nload can't. Now I'm using tcpdump, which is very powerful.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem, but I still want to share my solution.

Give the top will refresh the output, actually it doesn't dump the output, so it requires to dump data only once rather and stop the refresh.

```
Linux:
top -bn1 
OS X: 
top -l 1
```

thus, you can catch the output as normal.